# Understanding Born's rule for non-hermitian Hamiltonians

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Say I have a non-Hermitian hamiltonian, such as one might have in an incomplete description of a system where the states are allowed to decay. Then probabilities are not conserved since magnitudes will decrease with time. In particular, say I have an eigenfunction $\mid \psi \rangle$ with $\langle \psi \mid \psi \rangle \sim e^{-kt}$, so that $\psi$ is normalized at $t=0$ (before any decay), but the probability of encountering $\psi$ decreases with increasing $t$.

My question is about the probability of finding $\psi$. If I pick a generic state $\mid \alpha \rangle$, I can calculate the probability that measuring $\psi$ gives $\mid \alpha \rangle$ by $\mid \langle \alpha \mid \psi \rangle \mid^2$. Now if I merely want to find my probability of finding $\mid \psi \rangle$ at all, then I would do the same as above but with $\alpha = \psi$, hence I compute $\mid \langle \psi \mid \psi \rangle \mid^2$. this feel very weird since now I am looking at $\mid \psi \mid^4$ as opposed to $\mid \psi \mid^2$, which is usually what we interpret at the probability.

What is going on here? (Note that I bring up a system with decay so that it genuinely matters what the exponent is. In a usual system, $\mid \psi \mid^2 = 1$ so it doesn't matter what power is chosen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have $\langle \psi(t) | \psi(0) \rangle = A e^{-k t}$, for some normalization constant $A$.

Then the probability for the system to be in state $|\psi \rangle$ at time $t$ is

\begin{equation}
P_\psi(t) = |\langle \psi(t) | \psi(0) \rangle |^2 = |A|^2 e^{-2kt}.
\end{equation}

I feel this answer is a little glib but I am not sure where you are stuck actually.

Comment: Let me exapnd a bit, though I think you've answered my question. As a thought experiment, suppose I have $N>>1$ particles in state $\mid \psi \rangle$ at time $t = 0$, how many will be left at some later time $t = T$? I would compute this as $N \mid \psi(T) \mid^2 = N \langle \psi(T) \mid \psi(T) \rangle$. However, if we are measuring the probability that $\mid \psi \rangle$ is in state $\mid \alpha \rangle$ at time $T$, this is $\mid \langle \alpha \mid \psi(T) \rangle \mid^2$ but taking $\alpha = \psi(T)$ we get $\mid\langle \psi(T) \mid \psi(T) \rangle\mid^2$, which is not what we had.

Comment: I think maybe your confusion might just be getting wrapped up in notation. First, forget about time, and note that $|\langle \alpha | \psi\rangle |^2 = |\psi(\alpha)|^2$ -- the "ket" is the function and the "bra" is the argument of the function. You don't *have* to think of it that way, but my point is that the bra and ket are different objects. In particular, I wouldn't think of $|\langle \psi | \psi \rangle|^2$ as being like a function $\psi(x)$ raised to the fourth power. Inserting a complete set of states, it is more like $\int d \alpha |\psi(\alpha)|^2$...

Comment: ...For the example you are considering, I think you have the right basic idea, but just need to be a bit more careful about the notation. Say that these particles are all bosons, and they all either live in a state with energy $E_0$ or else they decay. Then the probability to find a given particle in the $E_0$ state is $| \langle \psi(t) | \psi(0) \rangle |^2 = |\langle \psi(0) | e^{-i H t} | \psi(0)\rangle|^2 = e^{-2 k t} |\langle \psi(0) | \psi(0) \rangle|^2 = e^{-2 k t}$. Then the average number of particles remaining is $N e^{-2kt}$.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you for clarifying.